# how databinding really work in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I was wondering if it could be possible to create a databinding system in pure actionscript without using mx.binding.utils.
At least I would like to know what is the overhead of the databinding code and how exactly the  ChangeWatcher knows when a property has been changed.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Diving in the Flex Data Binding Waters by Michael Labriola: http://www.ruffkutmedia.com/tutorials-diving-in-the-data-binding-waters-by-michael-labriola.htm (video) - slideshare here: http://www.slideshare.net/michael.labriola/diving-in-the-flex-data-binding-waters-presentation

There's a lot of work that goes on behind the scenes when you bind data, but he gives a really good explanation of how it works. It's a bit awkward to create something that works automatically unless you're passing through a "compile" phase where you add code.

You can also check out the as3 commons byecode project: http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-bytecode/index.html which should let you add code at runtime

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it is very likely using reflection...and that's it as I thought it generates setters and getters. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

The flex compiler actually compiles your MXML/AS3 to pure AS3 before it compiles it all to bytecode anyway. So at some stage in the compile process, data-binding is actually being implemented with ActionScript.

The problem is that Flex adds a bit of syntax specifically for data-binding. There is nothing stopping you from creating a data-binding system in AS3, but there are limitations, such as you would have to do it in an AS3 way.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. The main question is: how does databiding work under the hood? I could do maybe a referencing system, but that would become a naive two-way databinding. I could do through events, but how can I know if the property has been changed? Should I check it in a enterframe? The overhead sounds to be too much in this case. Let me know your thoughts thanks.